# managing git and svn at the same time?

Tags: git, svn

I have a group working on some commercial code in a private git repository.

The people I'm working for are using subversion/beanstalk.

What i need to do is take a copy of the latest release from git, merge in any changes from subversion, scrub (squash?) all the commits we've made in git and then commit to the beanstalk repository.

What's the easiest/cleanest way to do this? At the moment I'm finding it very difficult to manage!

Answer (score 2):

Read this:

http://www.viget.com/extend/effectively-using-git-with-subversion/